# password could not be set

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server

am using an Xserve version 10.5.7, when I try to change the password of any of my clients the following error comes up, "The password could not be set. All othe setting were saved. Erro 14120".

can any one help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You've not been terribly descriptive of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look towards the bottom of this post, someone has detailed a **[step-by-step guide](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6612150#6612150)** on how to resolve this problem (14120), and others have confirmed that the fix works...

Comment: Direct link: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6612150#6612150

Answer (score 0):

I would make a backup of your Open Directory data and then demote the server to a Standalone server. Reboot. Promote your server to a full Open Directory Master. Reboot. And then restore your Open Directory data from the data you backed up.